# How do I find any unused dependency injections in an Angular Controller?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

For example I injected $http, but I am not using it. How to find this is an unused dependency in any Angular method or tool?

Comment: If its not used it means unused

Comment: you can try to remove them one at a time and see what breaks, if nothing has changed, then that dependency is not used

Comment: Not manually but by any method or tool that tells me that this dependency is injected but not used anywhere for this page.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a similar answer.

I've stumbled on something that might answer your question, using [eslint-plugin-angular](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/), which has a [di-unused](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/docs/rules/di-unused.md) rule. This should highlight any removable dependencies for you.

I've not tried it myself as my problem is slightly different.